# Prolog: slash separated string to list

Tags: string, list, prolog

I have a string like `'/home/user/something/'` and I want to convert it to `['/', 'home', '/', 'user', '/', 'something', '/']`

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you not understand ?

Comment: I'm really new to prolog and do not understand most things :/. I can't even imagine how to solve it in prolog

Comment: [`atomics_to_string/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atomics_to_string/3) and [`atomic_list_concat/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atomic_list_concat/3) are what you want. These should have been named `intersperse_to_string/3` and `intersperse_to_atom/3` respectively. The problem, however, is that final `/` in the output list. Where does it come from?

Comment: Oh, it was just me forgot to type it. :D. Also thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1-** `s` predicate takes the input and gives the final split answer.

**2-** `split_string` is used to return just the words, so it returns `L = ["home", "user", "something"]`. Notice we don't have the `/`.

**3-** Now we need to add the `"/"`. We use `addslash` predicate, before every word we add a `"/"`. For the last `"/"` it checks the base predicate and the last `"/"` is added to the list.

```
s(X,L1):-
    split_string(X, "/", "/", L),
    addslash(L,L1).

addslash([],["/"]).
addslash([H|T],[H1,H|L]):-
    H1="/",
    addslash(T,L).


?- s('/home/user/something/', L).
L = ["/", "home", "/", "user", "/", "something", "/"]
```

Comment: This code adds forcibly adds a prefix slash and a suffix slash. But what if we don't want these? As in: `s('relative/path/four',X).`, then we get `X = ["/", "relative", "/", "path", "/", "four", "/"].` That may be too much.

Comment: I have answered based on what the asker has asked for. He/she clearly did not mention about the test cases that you are pointing to.

Comment: Experience with "stable business requirements" and "school assignments" and "oh that one more case when" has taught me deep distrust in what's being stated.

Comment: I understand what you mean.